# Pure JavaScript syntax for react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

I am trying to make a front-end with React for an application with Java back-end. Thus, I'm only trying to incorporate React in my JavaScript and html by adding scripts. I don't necessarily want to use Babel for JSX syntax, but the pure JavaScript syntax for React is confusing me a lot as I am very new to React.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
const e = React.createElement;
return e(
        'button',
        {className: 'whiteButton', onClick: () => this.setState({
                            clicked: false})},
        'Click Me Again'    
    );
```

Now, if I want to add this button inside a div and so on, how would I go about it? How will the React.createElement(components, props, ...children) work with respect to syntax?

I understand the concept it's just that the syntax is giving me a hard time.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Note: Since I am very new to React and guidance would greatly be appreciated as well.

Comment: Probably https://github.com/kay-is/react-from-zero can help you.

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . What is e? It's unclear what the question is. Are you asking how to write JSX in plain JS? You can check Babel output, for starters.

Comment: @estus I have updated what e is. And yes, I wanted to write JSX in plain JavaScript. Will look into the babel output.

Comment: I don't think there's much of a difference in how you'd bootstrap an app that doesn't use JSX. See [docs/hello-world](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html). For example, `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Hello, World!'), document.getElementById('root'));` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
    "div",
                            null,
                            React.createElement("e", null)
), document.getElementById('app'));

const e = React.createElement(
         "button",
          { className: "whiteButton", onclick: () => 
this.setState({clicked: false }) },
  "'Click Me Again'"
);
```

Try the above code. And also you can use the this tool to convert the jsx to pure js.
http://infoheap.com/online-react-jsx-to-javascript/